# How can I build jQuery like events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I would like to build a function which calls some event handlers based on a result, just like jQuery's `$.ajax()` it does. For example you can define this ajax code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "http://domainname.tld",
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function(e)
{
    //succed

}).fail(function(e)
{
    //error
});
```

I would like to get these:

```
.done(function(e)
    {
        //succed
    
    }
```

blocks to work with my function. At the moment I do something like this:

```
function SendRequest(arg1, arg2, onSuccess, onError)
{
    if(true)
    {
        onSuccess(true);
    }
    else
    {
        onError(false);
    }
}
```

and have to call it like this

```
SendRequest("someArg1", "someArg2", function(returnValue) { alert(returnValue); }, function(returnValue) { alert(returnValue); });
```

and would like to call it like this:

```
SendRequest("someArg1", "someArg2")
.onSuccess(
    function(returnValue)
    {
        alert(returnValue);
    })
.onError(function(returnValue)
{
    alert(returnValue);
});
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [q promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: I think [jquery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) is what you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@arun-p-johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) and [@hindmost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost) for giving me the right keywords to search and finally resolve my problem!

After reading [this](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/) great article I came up with the following solution:

```
function AsyncMethod(arg1, arg2)
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    //Do your work
    if(arg1 == arg2)
    {
        // true represents the result, optional
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }else{
        // Something went wrong, reject. (false is still the result, therefor it's also optional)
        deferred.reject(false);
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
$.when(
    AsyncMethod(true, false)
    .done(function (returnValue)
    {
        alert(arg1 + " == " + arg2);
    })

    .fail(function (returnValue)
    {
        alert(arg1 + " != " + arg2);
    });
);
```